# What's the best possible way to match one password

Tags: math

lets say I have a 8 digital password, say 12abCD!@

The password contains digital number(0-9), letters(uppercase and lowercase) and other character !@#$%^&*().

What is the lowest time of tries can I match the password and why?

Comment: One guess, if you're lucky.

Comment: Zero is lower than one, this can be achieved by not trying at all

Comment: this would be `brute force` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search

Answer (score 2):

To arrive at an accurate estimate you need to calculate 2 things:

FIRST: You need to use mathematic combinatorics:
each character in the password could be:
 - a lower case letter  [26]
 - an upper case letter [26]
 - a digit              [10]
 - a special character  [11]

given the number of possibilities each character could be one of 73 possibilities. This means 73 possibilities for the first character, 73 possibilities for the second, 73 possibilities for the third and so forth. This can be represented mathematically as:

```
73*73*73*...*73 or 73^n where n is the number of characters in your password
```

SECOND: You need to calculate the time it takes to guess a password. if your machine is slower this could be half a million a second. If your machine is very fast it could be 15 million a second. Check this [site](http://daleswanson.org/things/password.htm) or [this one](http://geodsoft.com/cgi-bin/crakcalc.pl) for a good estimate based on guesses per second.

In short the estimation algorithm goes like this:

1. You take the search space (number of possibilities)
2. Divided the search space by the guesses per seconds to get the number of seconds to guess the entire search space,
3. Then divide the time by 2 to get the *average* time to guess *a password* in the search space.

*Colonel Panic* was right, if you get lucky it only takes one guess and that is the lowest number of times to guess that one password. However the average time to guess the password is probably what you are looking for and that is:

- 1.09 hours and 1.84 hours by each site's respective estimate at 1,000,000,000,000 checks a second (which is like NSA super computer speeds)
- 2.10 centuries and 210.37 years by each site's respective estimate at 1,000,000 checks a second (which is something my computer can do)

**NOTE:** I used the 93 printable ascii characters for these estimates *not* the 73 characters presented in the password

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number of attempts would be:

```
26 upper cases letters
26 lower case letters
10 integers
11 special characters

= 73

73^8 = 8.0646009e+14
```

The minimum of course, if you were lucky, would be 1

Comment: 11 special characters... the full stop is meant to be one of them me thinks

Comment: As Curt says 8.0646009e+14 would be the max tries, the lowest as Colonel says would be 1 if you are lucky but it could be anything between the two.